# How does Kafka remember a consumer so it can continue to consume the same partition

Tags: apache-kafka

let's say we have a topic that has two partitions p1 and p2 and there are two consumers c1 and c2 (they are in the same consumer group), so c1 and c2 are consuming p1 and p2 respectively.

when the client application instance (c1) is about to do the next polling, how does kafka know this polling request is coming from c1 so kafka can let c1 continue to consume p1 rather than p2 considering the http polling request is stateless, so unless c1 passes sth like `client.id` and kafka maintains a mapping between partition and consumers, otherwise kafka cannot know which partition it should let the request to consume.

But I checked the Kafka docs, it doesn't mention that client.id is used by kafka to track consumers, so how does Kafka remember a consumer so it can continue to consume the same partition in the next pollings?

Comment: "considering http is stateless" - Kafka is not using HTTP... `group.id` is used. Not `client.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kafka, meta data of maintaing a mapping between partition and consumers is stored in zookeeper or Kraft.

You can see mapping between partition No and consumer  id in the following example.

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group

  TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
  my-topic                       0          2               4               2          consumer-1-029af89c-873c-4751-a720-cefd41a669d6   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
  my-topic                       1          2               3               1          consumer-1-029af89c-873c-4751-a720-cefd41a669d6   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
  my-topic                       2          2               3               1          consumer-2-42c1abd4-e3b2-425d-a8bb-e1ea49b29bb2   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
```

Also, you can access zookeeper client to see details by following path:

```
/consumers/[groupId]/offsets/[topic]/[partitionId] -> long (offset)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so does kafka queries this mapping from zookeeper each time it receives a request?

Comment: @DongLiu The ConsumerGroup Coordinator distributes this information, yes